# why Pg_stat_progress_analyze did not show the progress of create index in PostgresSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

I am execute a create index command in PostgreSQL 13 like this:

```
CREATE INDEX dict_word_idx ON dict (word);
```

the dict table has more than 1000000 rows. The command takes a long time and I want to check the execute progress, then I am using this command to show the progress of create index command, but the `Pg_stat_progress_analyze` result shows 0 rows.This is my sql command:

```
select *
from Pg_stat_progress_analyze
```

why the `Pg_stat_progress_analyze` did  not show the execute progress?

Answer (score 1):

Because that shows the progress of ANALYZE.  Look in pg_stat_progress_create_index to see the progress of CREATE INDEX.

Comment: I check the `pg_stat_progress_create_index` view but still no ouput. @jjanes